# GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter method throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, gson

I am calling a method this way:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(CoindeskRateResult.class, CurrencyRateDeserializer.class)
```

CurrencyRateDeserializer is a `com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer`

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;

    public class CurrencyRateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CoindeskRateResult> {
        @Override
        public CoindeskRateResult deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                              JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            CoindeskRateResult result = new CoindeskRateResult();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The error occurs in the `GsonBuilder` class. I know that `typeAdapter` is an instance of `JsonDeserializer<?>` but `$Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`

```
  public GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object typeAdapter) {
    $Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument(typeAdapter instanceof JsonSerializer<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof JsonDeserializer<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof InstanceCreator<?>
            || typeAdapter instanceof TypeAdapter<?>);
....
```

StackTrace:

```
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Preconditions.checkArgument($Gson$Preconditions.java:46)
                at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GsonBuilder.java:472)*
    .....
```

My CoindeskRateResult class:

```
public class CoindeskRateResult {
    public Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(CoindeskRateResult.class, CurrencyRateDeserializer.class)
```

This is why all of the `instanceof` checks fail for the first case. What you're looking for is:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(CoindeskRateResult.class, new CurrencyRateDeserializer())
```

To be honest, I think this is a Gson design flaw.